# How to ensure that your excel or ssrs reports are correct?

Tags: sql-server, excel, reporting-services, reporting

I went for an interview yesterday having just finished my school. I did sql server training and excel in school.
One of the questions that was asked which according to the feedback let me down was

HOW DO YOU ENSURE THAT YOUR REPORTS ARE CORRECT?

The answer I gave was that I will look at the timeline and trend to check if there is consistency in the data.
Please guys any idea on how to answer this question?

If this question is off topic please if you can direct me to the appropriate forum. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I were asked i will give the following answers.

1. By validating the accuracy and completeness of the data
2. By comparing current report with historical Reports
3. By checking the report dates
4. Avoid Manual process as much as I can.
5. By Automating Report.

Comment: I'd agree with the above, but possibly elaborate more on point 1. If the report joins data from one or more tables then you need to check that the joins are returning the correct data from each of the referenced tables. You would also need to confirm that all the selection conditions are being checked. This may require specific test data being created to test each condition.

Answer (score 0):

Generate meaningful statistics (like sums and counts) that can be correlated back to the raw data.

And some pushback to the interviewers - What is the context? As a developer? As a user? As a tester?